# Even after entering the else of if -else the return statement is not working in Python?

Tags: python, return

```py
def quickSort(nums,start,end):    
    if(start < end):
        Pindex =partition(nums,start,end)
        quickSort(nums,start,Pindex-1)
        quickSort(nums,Pindex+1,end)   
    else:
        print("Else",start,end,nums)
        return nums;
```

The return statement is not executed even if the print ("Else",start,end,nums0 is executed

Comment: why do you say the return statement isn't executed?  how are you calling quickSort()?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are ignoring the return values from your recursive `quickSort` calls (which, by the way, is conventionally spelled `quicksort`).

So even though your base case (the `else`) returns a value, it will subsequently be discarded.

You need to handle the return values of both recursive `quicksort` calls:

1. the first result needs to be assigned to a variable which you subsequently use for the *next* `quicksort` call
2. the second result needs to be returned

Adjusting the code, and fixing the formatting, we get:

```
def quicksort(nums, start, end):
    if start < end:
        pindex = partition(nums, start, end)
        nums = quicksort(nums, start, pindex - 1)
        return quicksort(nums, pindex + 1, end)
    else:
        return nums
```

Furthermore, it is conventional to handle the base case of a recursion *first*, because then we don’t need to indent as much (since we also don’t need the `else`):

```
def quicksort(nums, start, end):
    if start >= end:
        return nums

    pindex = partition(nums, start, end)
    nums = quicksort(nums, start, pindex - 1)
    return quicksort(nums, pindex + 1, end)
```